# dplyr pivot in combination with counts

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, count, pivot

I have a data set where columns are factors that all have the same levels. Rows are observations. The goal is to create a table where rows are the factors and columns are counts of the answer categories.
Here is an example:

```
rating <- c("yes", "no", "totally")
coke<-factor(c('yes', "yes", NA, "no"), levels=rating)
icecream<-factor(c("yes", "no", "totally", "no"),levels=rating)
cookie<-factor(c("no", NA, "no","yes"),levels=rating) 
df<-tibble(coke,icecream,cookie)
df
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  coke  icecream cookie
  <fct> <fct>    <fct> 
1 yes   yes      no    
2 yes   no       NA    
3 NA    totally  no    
4 no    no       yes
```

The desired output would look like this:

```
mat<-matrix(c(2,1,0,1,1,2,1,0,1,1,0,1),byrow=T, 3,4, dimnames=list(c("coke","icecream","cookie"), c("yes","no","totally",NA)))
mat
         yes no totally <NA>
coke       2  1       0    1
icecream   1  2       1    0
cookie     1  1       0    1
```

I was partially successful to do this for each variable at a time

```
df %>% 
  count(coke)%>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = coke, values_from = n)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps:

1. Make the data longer (note: the data is much easier to work with in this state, so I recommend keeping it in this state when doing data analysis, if you can)
2. Make it wide again, getting the length of each list value (count does something else)

```
df |> 
  pivot_longer(everything()) |>
  pivot_wider(id_cols = name, names_from = value, values_fn = length, values_fill = 0)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 5
  name       yes    no  `NA` totally
  <chr>    <int> <int> <int>   <int>
1 coke         2     1     1       0
2 icecream     1     2     0       1
3 cookie       1     2     1       0
```